# Why does the "ls -l /bin" command show only 1 file?

Tags: 20.04, files, ls

The `ls /bin` command shows many files. I need to get a detailed list. But the `ls -l /bin` command shows only 1 file.

Tell me, please, what is wrong?

Comment: `$ ls -l $(echo $PATH  | tr ':' '\n')` will show you "all" your executables, and also where they or the /bin dirs are linked to, if that is the case.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.

`/bin` is a symlink that points to `/usr/bin`.

When you use the `ls /bin` command, the symlink is followed, and you're shown the contents of `/usr/bin` (where the symlink points).

However, with the `ls -l /bin` command, the symlink is not followed, and only the symlink itself is shown.

The reason may be found under the `--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir` option in the ls texinfo documentation (`info ls` or `info coreutils 'ls invocation'`):

```
‘--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir’
     Do not dereference symbolic links, with one exception: if a command
     line argument specifies a symbolic link that refers to a directory,
     show information for that directory rather than for the link
     itself.  This is the default behavior when no other
     dereferencing-related option has been specified (‘--classify’
     (‘-F’), ‘--directory’ (‘-d’), (‘-l’), ‘--dereference’ (‘-L’), or
     ‘--dereference-command-line’ (‘-H’)).
```

In this context, `-l` is an *"other dereferencing-related option"* and turns the behavior off.

If you use `ls -lH /bin`, you tell the command to specifically follow symlinks, and now you (properly) see the contents of `/usr/bin`.

`/bin` being a symlink to `/usr/bin` follows the [UsrMerge](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge) package, which was introduced in Debian 10 in 2019, and thus adopted by the following versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Another way to force dereferencing is to use `ls -l /bin/`